# Is it possible extract/delete part of oracle data dump?

Tags: database-administration, oracle-11g

We have an Oracle 11g schema and data dump. As this dump is very large, I would like to extract only part of schema with data. Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Is it a simple SQL file? If yes, `grep` comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

[IMPDP](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/dp_import.htm) does have some options.
Firstly you can choose to only import specific schemas (which is useful if you've done a full database export)

Secondly you can choose to INCLUDE or EXCLUDE specific objects or objects where the name matches a particular format.

Thirdly there is a QUERY parameter that "Allows you to specify a query clause that filters the data that gets imported."

If you are using the older EXP/IMP utilities, then you miss out on that flexibility

Answer (score 1):

IMP also has some flexibility. If you know what schema(s)/table(s) you want to import, then use the TABLES keyword to specify them.

Without knowing exactly what produced your "dump", it's a bit difficult to provide definitive answers. Also, do you want certain tables restored, or just parts of certain tables?

Answer (score 0):

If you're taking about the dump generated using `exp`/`expdp` tools - then probably* no

**There is a tool called [NXTract](http://www.kiyoinc.com/nxtract.html) but I'm skeptical about it and haven't tried it.*